# Default query parameter values in Azure Functions bindings

Tags: azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I am using the Azure Functions SQL Extension.

I have an endpoint with the following parameters ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql-input?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-javascript#configuration)).

```
"parameters": "@Limit={Query.limit},@Status={Query.status}",
```

Does anyone know whether it's possible to assign default/null values to Query parameters? E.g. if i don't specify status in my HTTP query string i want it to be null.

Currently it fails with the message:

```
Error while accessing 'status': property doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set default values. Here are alternatives you could consider

1. If using C#, then you can [Bind at Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#binding-at-runtime)
2. Use a separate HTTP function that would call the function with the SQL binding after validating and setting defaults. You could even consider [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview) here, if it makes sense for your scenario
3. Directly use the SQL SDK